# client_secrets.json file unreadable once deployed to GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client

I have an app that works using `dev_appserver.py` on my machine. I deploy it successfully:

```
ronj@l:~$ appcfg.py update myapp/
03:03 PM Host: appengine.google.com
03:03 PM Application: myapp; version: 1
...
03:03 PM Completed update of app: myapp, version: 1
```

My app uses the Google API, so this deployment includes a `client_secrets.json` file, which lives at the root of my project folder. And it seems it is correctly deployed, because I get it when re-downloading my app (with `appcfg.py download_app -A myapp -V 1 ~/myapp`).

However, when opening a page that calls a script needing access to `client_secrets.json`, I get a `Error: Server Error`, and here is what the instance logs show (myapp and MYID censored):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 196, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 255, in _LoadHandler
    handler = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/myapp.py", line 42, in <module>
    YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/oauth2client/util.py", line 128, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/oauth2client/appengine.py", line 854, in __init__
    client_type, client_info = clientsecrets.loadfile(filename, cache=cache)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 145, in loadfile
    return _loadfile(filename)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/oauth2client/clientsecrets.py", line 107, in _loadfile
    raise InvalidClientSecretsError('File not found: "%s"' % filename)
InvalidClientSecretsError: File not found: "/base/data/home/apps/s~myapp/1.MYID/client_secrets.json"
```

Here are **lines 41 and 42 of `myapp.py`**:

```
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
    YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)
```

and here is **`CLIENT_SECRETS`**:

```
CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: murph on #appengine mentioned that may come from incorrect `app.yaml` configuration, and that I should *"Make sure it's not in `app.yaml` being served as a static file, and make sure any of your own code doesn't decide to serve it"*, but even after removing all static handlers to that file, the problem persists. Here's a [pastebin to my app.yaml](http://pastebin.com/Ev5kxjSF). And talking about that, I noticed that if I leave client_secrets.json and deploy, I see *"Cloning 6 static files"*. Then if I delete it and re-deploy, I see *"Cloning 5 static files"*. Does that confirm there is still something in my `app.yaml` that matches `client_secrets.json`, or are these separate mechanisms?

Comment: The secrets is in your root; Have you tried : decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets('client_secrets.json',
    YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SCOPE)

Comment: @voscausa Yes I did, same error :-/ . Note I just made an edit at the end of my original post, does that give you other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, the "js"on matches

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|ico))
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|ico))
```

Try this instead

```
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|ico)$)
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|ico)$)
```

Comment: Yes! You win my (dusty) regexp-hat for today :) , thank you !

Comment: As a rule, you should try and keep your static assets seperate from code/stuff you want to access from the filesystem. Then you won't get strange clashes with regexs for static resources.